# Optimizing query with two MAX columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to optimize below query

```
 SELECT  
     Id, -- identity
     CargoID,
     [Status] AS CurrentStatus
 FROM    
     dbo.CargoStatus
 WHERE   
     id IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID
            FROM dbo.CargoStatus CS
            INNER JOIN STD.StatusMaster S ON CS.ShipStatusID = S.SatusID
            WHERE CS.CargoID=CargoStatus.CargoID
            ORDER BY YEAR([CS.DATE]) DESC, MONTH([CS.DATE]) DESC, 
                     DAY([CS.DATE]) DESC, S.StatusStageNumber DESC)
```

There are two tables

1. `CargoStatus`, and
2. `StatusMaster`

   - `Statusmaster` has columns `StatusID, StatusName, StatusStageNumber(int)`
   - `CargoStatus` has columns `ID, StatusID (FK StatusMaster StatusID column), Date`

Is there any other better way of writing this query.

I want latest status for each cargo (only one entry per `cargoID`).

Answer (score 6):

Since you seem to be using SQL Server 2005 or newer, you can use a CTE with the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function:

```
;WITH LatestCargo AS
(
   SELECT 
       cs.Id, -- identity
       cs.CargoID,
       cs.[Status] AS CurrentStatus
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cs.CargoID 
                         ORDER BY cs.[Date], s.StatusStageNumber DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM 
       dbo.CargoStatus cs
   INNER JOIN 
       STD.StatusMaster s ON cs.ShipStatusID = s.[StatusID]
)
SELECT 
    Id, CargoID, [Status]
FROM 
    LatestCargo 
WHERE 
    RowNum = 1
```

This CTE "partitions" your data by `CargoID`, and for each partition, the `ROW_NUMBER` function hands out sequential numbers, starting at 1 and ordered by `Date DESC` - so the latest row gets `RowNum = 1` (for each `CargoID`) which is what I select from the CTE in the SELECT statement after it.

Comment: hi @marc_s wil it return only one row per cargoid. i tried but it is not working for me

Comment: i need to return only top (latest status by date desc,stagenumber desc) row for each cargoid but as whole table not a single row

Comment: @AamodThakur: this will return **one roe for EACH `CargoID`** - so if you have 10 `CargoID` values - you'll get 10 rows.

Comment: there are more than one status for each cargo in CargoStatuses table, so output i am getting is multiple statuses per cargoid. eg: 344 cargoid has 2 statuses Pickedup and Delivered so it is showing both the statues in the resultant table

Comment: @AamodThakur: you need to either make that database available to me so I can check this - or you're not doing it right. With the `PARTITION BY CargoID` there **ought** to be just a single row **per `CargoID`** ....